# RabbitMQ Memory Usage - Binaries / Queues do not match up

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, erlang

- RabbitMQ 3.6.9
- Erlang 19.3
- Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

We have a RabbitMQ cluster with 3 servers. One of the servers is presenting an unusually high memory consumption which I can quite figure why.

When I check how that server is using the memory, I get this graph pointing me to Binaries and when I check the Binaries it tells me it's used by queues:

[image]

But when I check the queues they are using nothing even close to that +-500MB:

[image]

I have tried to run `rabbitmqctl eval '[garbage_collect(P) || P <- processes()].'`, but nothing really change.

Does that mean there is a memory leak? Am interpreting that information wrongly? How can I cleanup the Binaries memory?